# aws lambda concurrent executions metric and single one PartitionKey in the kinesis stream

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a kinesis stream configured as an event trigger for my aws lambda.
The kinesis trigger has a config like this:

```
  Activate trigger: Yes
  Authentication:[{}]
  Batch size: 10
  Batch window: 1
  Concurrent batches per shard: 1
  Last processing result: OK
  Maximum age of record: 10800
  On-failure destination: None
  Report batch item failures: No
  Retry attempts: None
  Split batch on error: No
  Starting position: LATEST
  Tumbling window duration: None
  UUID: b90da7ec-6e4c-4848-99f5-effa2cf5e0cf
```

I put some records to the kinesis stream with same PartitionKey but some minutes later I open the "Concurrent executions" metric and I see the next chart

[image]

In the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/key-concepts.html) I read

```
A partition key is used to group data by shard within a stream. Kinesis Data Streams
 segregates the data records belonging to a stream into multiple shards. It uses the
 partition key that is associated with each data record to determine which shard a 
given data record belongs to. Partition keys are Unicode strings, with a maximum 
length limit of 256 characters for each key. An MD5 hash function is used to map
 partition keys to 128-bit integer values and to map associated data records to 
shards using the hash key ranges of the shards. When an application puts data into 
a stream, it must specify a partition key.
```

Why my lambda executing concurrently? What I should do that that lambda proceed shard from kinesis sequentially without concurrency?